# How to replace libm when using ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, ctypes, clang++

I'm getting different results for the same shared library when a function (from the shared library) is executed by a standalone executable and when using Python's ctypes for calling the exact same function.
The difference was narrowed down to be the version of **libm** used by the library.
When using the library from a standalone executable we link against **openlibm**, but when the library is linked by ctypes, it's linked against **Ubuntu's libm**.
How can I make ctypes link my shared library against **openlibm**?

**The shared library header (fft.h):**

```
extern "C" {
void fft(const char* srcPath);
};
```

**The shared library implementation (fft.cpp):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/FFT>

void fft(const char* srcPath) {
    std::cout.precision(17);

    std::ifstream fs(srcPath, std::ofstream::in);

    // Get length of file
    fs.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
    auto length = fs.tellg();
    fs.seekg(0, std::ifstream::beg);

    // Read the file
    auto srcRaw = new char[length];
    fs.read(srcRaw, length);

    // Convert data to vector of doubles
    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(srcRaw);
    std::vector<double> srcDoubles = j;

    int n = 65536;

    Eigen::VectorXd srcEigen(n);
    Eigen::VectorXcd dstEigen(n);
    std::copy(srcDoubles.data(), srcDoubles.data() + srcDoubles.size(), srcEigen.data());

    Eigen::FFT<double> fft;
    fft.fwd(dstEigen, srcEigen);

    std::vector<std::complex<double>> dstTmp(dstEigen.data(), dstEigen.data() + dstEigen.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dstTmp.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Result[" << i << "] = " << dstTmp[i].real() << "+i*" << dstTmp[i].imag() << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] srcRaw;
}
```

**Using the library from a standalone executable:**

```
#include <fft.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    fft("input_data");
}
```

**Using Python's ctypes:**

```
from ctypes import c_char_p, CDLL


class LibCFft(CDLL):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LibCFft, self).__init__("libexample.so")
        self._addfunc('fft', [c_char_p], None)

    def _addfunc(self, name, argtypes, restype):
        attr = getattr(self, name)
        attr.argtypes = argtypes
        attr.restype = restype

        return lambda x: x


class CFft(object):
    def fft(self):
        LibCFft().fft("input_data")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CFft().fft()
```

**Lib build:**

```
clang++ /opt/eigen-eigen-43d9075b23ef -isystem /opt/spdlog/include -isystem /opt/nlohmann/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/example.dir/fft.cpp.o -c /home/user/fft.cpp

clang++ -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG -shared -Wl,-soname,libexample.so -o libbugatone.so CMakeFiles/example.dir/generated/fft.cpp.o -lopenlibm
```

**Executable build:**

```
clang++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -latomic -nodefaultlibs -lopenlibm -lc -lc++ -lgcc -lgcc_s -lstdc++ -latomic -lm  CMakeFiles/eigen_tester.dir/eigen_tester.cpp.o  -o eigen_tester libexample.so -lopenlibm
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I doubt that the 2 libraries are mismatched as their names differ (*libm.so\**, *vs.* *libopenlibm.so\**). So when *libexample.so* is loaded (no matter where from), the loader will automatically attempt to load *libopenlibm.so\**. Maybe your conclusion is wrong? Could you share some details (like tests, etc)?

Comment: For example, the `exp` function is looked for by its name. Both libs have their own version of `exp` so any call to `exp` can be redirected to either one of them.
When building my lib *without* `-lopenlibm` I get the same results (e.g. `exp` function results) as when I use my lib with ctypes. When building my lib *with* `-lopenlibm` I get the expected results when using my own executable but I get the wrong results when using ctypes to load this lib.

Comment: Try: `ldd example.so` Anyway, *ctypes* doesn't have anything to do with linking, it's dynamically loading. But, again without a *mcve* ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) it's hard to tell

Comment: `ldd` output is what I expect (openlibm appears there before libm).
ctypes is not linking, but I guess Python binary is loaded with libm so math function calls are done using libm and not openlibm (i.e. the priority between libraries changes).

Comment: Yes, *Python* executable (e.g. */usr/bin/python3*) is linked against *libm.so*, meaning that it will be loaded when you call *ctypes*. One way of making sure that you call the right function, is to load the dll and get the func pointer manually (`dlopen` / `dlsym`) in your *C++* code. But I don't know how scalable is that.

Comment: I have a similiar problem, my `.so` is _statically_ linked to `openlibm`, but it is still using functions from system's `libm` when invoked from `python`. :(
Do you have any news on this issue, @Karpad? Could you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

In the executable link step you use BOTH -lm and -lopenlibm which is probably not what you want.

-nodefaultlibs disables automatic inclusion of all standard libs, so if you simply not include -lm but keep -lopenlibm this should probably do what you want.

You colud update LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your environment, to point to your local library folder first, and keep your libopenlibm.so there and also create a soft link to it: 'ln -s libopenlibm.so libm.so'.
In most cases that would cause any shared objects to use this as a substitution to  a regular libm.so

Comment: My answer is directly applicable to the problem. Any executable that is linked with -nodefaultlibs and does not have -lm on the list of linker arguments will not be linked with it, and this is what the OP is asking as far as I understand the question, so, no, I won't be able to improve my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPolyudov Please note that the shared library is built without `-lm`. Only the executable is built with `-lm` - and it works as expected.
The problem is when using the shared library with ctypes, and in this scenario the executable is not used at all.

Comment: I got it, thank you. I updated the answer to cover the shared object case too.